# Odd capatilisation error in a tag feed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, feed

This link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/Agile

Takes me to a list of questions with the tag "gile"

I use it as a "live bookmark" in firefox, and as far as I can see the list there is up-to-date (with Agile tagged questions!)

Do I need to do anything else to report the anomaly?

Comment: You do realize that tags are always in lower case, right?  It's a bug all right, but it's also a mistake to use a link to "Agile" when the tag will be "agile".

Comment: At some point *it* generated that URL for me.

Comment: I don't know how we could have ever generated that URL for you. It is a bug, but .. show me where the url containing "Agile" exists in the system?

Comment: It is an old link... possibly back from beta time and I am not quite sure how I made it! As I say it is a 'live bookmark' that sits on my FireFox links bar. Is it possible that in the dim and distant past tags allowed case? Certainly I don't seem to be able to generate a similar link from a search or tag now.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to strip ***any*** capital letters from the tag, definitely a bug.

Equivalent to "java" tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/THEjCAPITALaLETTERSvAREaSTRIPPED