# Tags with capitalization behave oddly

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

If you go to the page for a tag that doesn't exist but is all lower-case, such as [pony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pony).  But, if you went to the page for [PONY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/PONY), which also doesn't exist, odd things happen:

1. You get a listing of all questions, just as if you'd gone to the newest questions without any tags.
2. The text on the right says (currently) "217,570 questions tagged", but doesn't show the tag.  In looking at the page source, there isn't anything in the div where the tag should be.

I don't know if it makes more sense to redirect to the lowercased version of the tag, or just give the standard "0 questions tagged PONY", but the current behavior certainly doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Pony", huh? If you want to find those posts, just go to TheTXI's profile. They're all there. =)

Comment: "pony" is interchangeable with "foo", only more adorable.

Comment: I think this is a dupe. There was another question along these lines and the reason was an initial capital on the tag. I can't find the post right now, though I will keep looking.

Comment: Here we go - check this question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/odd-capatilisation-error-in-a-tag-feed

Comment: I didn't see another one, but if it is, by all means close it.  Of course, if that's the explanation given in the other thread, don't close this one because that only explains why it happens, not why it *should* happen.

Comment: Probably because you spelled "capitalization" correctly...

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: the other spelling is considered correct in the UK, fyi

Answer (score 5):

[It is stripping all capital letters out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/odd-capatilisation-error-in-a-tag-feed/3174#3174) for some reason.  Since you're giving it all caps, your tag gets turned to empty string, so it's like you're browsing all posts.

Comment: Yeah, but the behavior is still weird.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to imply that this was *correct*.  i was more trying to narrow it down so that it will be easier for the SO team to fix.  i agree that it is definitely a bug.