# Tags with uppercase characters get cut

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Tagging a question with a term with an uppercase first letter (e.g. `Zend-Framework`) results in the first letter of each word being cut off (`end-ramework`).

This happens only if ONLY the first character is uppercase. If the whole word is ("CSV"), it gets converted to lowercase as expected.

Reproduced in Chrome 5 and Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Same here (also Chrome 5).

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: sorry. But doesn't it only get CWed if Pekka does 8 edits himself? Otherwise this would be a backdoor for non-mods to force CW upon a question

Comment: @Tob: No, everyone can force it into CW. I do not if you need 8, 10, or 15 edits. This has changed over time.

Comment: @Tobias: [it's a](http://files.myopera.com/freejerk/files/bug-feature.jpg) [feature](http://carthik.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/feature-bug.jpg)

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: isn't this considered a serious flaw? One single user could make 8 (or how many ever) edits and the transition to CW is still irreversible, I assume

Comment: Same thing happens adding an "Interesting" tag; type it with an uppercase, click Add then refresh the page. FF 3.6.8 / WinXP

Comment: @Tob: Well, for misuse we have moderators, but honestly the opposite is true. It was implemented to auto-cw stuff which shows a big community interest, i.e it is changed by a lot of users. Then you cannot say anymore, that the OP is the owner, because the content changed too much. There were several proposals, to get rid of this limit, if the OP is the only one changing the question. But it was declined.

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: That does make sense, but do retags count as real edits? (And even mod can't undo CWing AFIAK)

Comment: @Tob: I think they count, because till recently there was no difference for 2K users between retagging and changing the whole question. But I could be wrong. No-one can undo it. You have to manipulate the database tables directly and I doubt Jeff will do that :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3404853/revisions was tagged [ava] first, I guess the OP wanted [Java]

Comment: @Tobias: As a side note, I'm not too impressed with leppie's edit comment there...

Comment: @Jon You are not alone there, see [this complaint](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59564/complaint-against-user-who-edited-my-post)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/tags-with-capitalization-behave-oddly/4354#4354 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/odd-capatilisation-error-in-a-tag-feed/3174#3174

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is fixed.