# After question submission, tags seems to have last letter removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478191/is-it-possible-to-debug-a-asp-net-web-application-thats-not-started-from-within) on StackOverflow and when I submitted the tags, two of the tags had the last letters removed.  For example, I submitted:

```
ASP.NET .NET
```

and after I submitted the question, the tags were:

```
ASP.NE .NE
```

It might be worth noting that I don't always wait for the javascript autocompletion to fill in the tag for me on popular tags such as `ASP.NET` and `.NET`.

This has happened before. The first time I saw it happen, I thought that maybe I had typed it in wrong, so I didn't worry about it.  But this time around, I'm sure I typed it in correctly.  What might be going on?

*My Machine: Win XP SP3 with IE8.*

Comment: Running XP SP3 and IE8 here, I can't seem to reproduce this neither here nor on SO. Is the textbox actually showing "asp.net" and ".net" before you hit submit?

Comment: Opposite of this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59556/tags-with-uppercase-characters-get-cut

Comment: Nope, it's the dot. `NOTAGS` works `NO.TAGS` doesn't.

Comment: @Grace Yes, the textbox actually shows asp.net and .net before I click submit, but I'm not sure of the *case* of my text.

Comment: @Ladybug you think the problem is with the `.` in the tag?

Comment: @Ben: Yes, I do.

Comment: Reproduced.  Se above.

Comment: Looks like it's the combination of capital letters and the period. I didn't have a problem when I did it using lowercase, but everyone else's ability to reproduce seems to lean towards this.

Comment: @Grace: The hyphen `-` also causes this, e.g. `[ALWAYS-FRIDAY-IN-ICELAND]` &rarr; `[always-friday-in-icelan]`

Comment: Also `C+C -> C` ... `C++C` and tags with `#` work though.

Comment: I had exactly this happen yesterday with the tag `space-quest-II`: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/5217/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Uppercase, meh.